# Raspberry pi 3 /etc/inittab empty

Tags: boot, login

i have this new RPi3 and the first time i used it there were no login during startup but now that i continued using it after 3 weeks, there's this login window that i cannot pass through even though i only have one user (pi) and inputted the correct password (raspberry).

I did some research and found a way to automatically login during boot by adding [something](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login) in the /etc/inittab, but when i try to open it the file is just empty, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a very similar question here somewhere but I'll give you a quick answer rather than digging around for it.

First, beware when reading Pi related blogs, tutorials, etc. online (including questions here) to check the date, because things can change over time, as they have in this case.  **Unfortunately**, not everyone who posts information online seems to consider this relevant, as in this case -- being [mediawiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) based, *elinux* articles require you to look through the [View History](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Debian_Auto_Login&action=history) tab to get the date.

So this time you are mostly blameless, but that page has not been updated in almost 3 1/2 years.

Anyway, `/etc/inittab` is a relic of [SysV init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style), which was used by Debian (and therefore Raspbian) up until version 8 (the current one as of about a year ago -- and note there was no Raspbian 1-6, it started at 7, the numbers follow Debian, which has been around for a few decades).

The replacement for SysV init is **systemd**; as per bluepinto's answer the easiest way to set up autologin in any case is via `raspi-config` (which has been kept up to date with changes to the init system).

Answer (score 2):

`inittab` was a part of SysVinit, which was replaced by systemd. Serial getty is a service now, and it can disabled or stopped like this:

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

For more information, take a look at this thread in the rpi forum.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=123081

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `raspi-config`. It has what you are looking for. Also see the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md).

I really like Debian, but I find it too buggy on Pi3. Maybe if you have an extra SD card lying around you can try [Lubuntu for Pi3](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/). But this will need a SD card larger than 4Gb. The image will fit on 4Gb SD card but trying to upgrade, there will be a squeeze on space