# Simple command line to write and read data from UART (serial) loopback

Tags: uart

I want to connect the TX and RX pins together and from the command line echo some text into `/dev/ttyAMA0` and tail the result (from somewhere).  I ultimately want to communicate with an Arduino but first I want to understand how to configure the Pi serial UART and its capabilities; also I don't have a voltage converter chip like a CD4050 yet.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero with Raspian 4.14 (2019-04-08, Stretch Lite).

I have used [raspi-config](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md) to disable the login shell from being accessible over serial and left the serial port hardware enabled.  I rebooted the device.  `/boot/config.txt` now has the line `enable_uart=1`.

I have connected a DVM (I don't have an oscilloscope) to TX (pin 8) and when I issue the following commands I can see the voltage drop briefly from 3.3 V.  This is consistent with the logic level being pulled low during sending data:

```
$ sudo su root
$ echo "hello" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I was hoping that if I connect the TX and RX (pin 10) together, then when I issue the following commands it would show `hello` that was stored in the buffer:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

This doesn't work as it blocks, presumably waiting for data.  If I have two terminals open and use:

```
# terminal 1
$ tail /dev/ttyAMA0

# terminal 2
$ echo "hello" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

In terminal 1 no text is received.  Additionally the voltage drops to 1.15 V and stays there.  Using Ctrl+C in terminal 1 results in the TX-RX voltages to go to 0 volts.

On disconnecting the TX and RX pins from each other, the RX pin returns to high (3.3 V) and the TX pins remains at low (0 V).  Keeping the pins separated again and issuing `echo "hello" > /dev/ttyAMA0` results in the TX pin voltage increasing to 1.15 V (?!).  Issuing the command `echo "hello" > /dev/ttyAMA0` again results in it returning to 3.3 V.

I obviously have not yet found the right materials to understand how serial / TTY works / how to configure the raspberry pi.

A lot of the older tutorials say you need to edit `/etc/inittab` but [as this has been removed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50652/10051) I have ignored this.  Additionally a lot of the older tutorials called for editing `/boot/cmdline.txt` to replace `console=tty1` with `console=ttyAMA0,9600 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,9600 console=tty1`.  This doesn't make much sense to me as I *don't* want to use the `ttyAMA0` for console.  I do want to use `ttyAMA0` as a file descriptor to write / read from.

Comment: Some Pis (the ones with Bluetooth) will default to /dev/ttyS0 for the UART on GPIO 14/15.

Comment: Thanks @joan.  I don't see a `/dev/ttyS0` device on my Pi.  Additionally I know the `/dev/ttyAMA0` is doing something on both read and write due to the behaviour of the voltages associated with the TX and RX pins as I issue different commands interacting with the `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

Comment: If you want to see activity on the UART you could use my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or the command line [monitor GPIO](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).

Comment: Thanks @joan I'll check it out! :)

Comment: @ AJP - If the final goal of your serial loopback experiments is to connect Arduino to Rpi, then you might be interested to read my answers to a similar question - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96184/serial-to-arduino-totally-non-responsive you might also like to search in this forum "serial loopback" to find more answers you might find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason nothing happens is because you are sending to the UART, but not reading.

Try

```
cat < /dev/serial0
```

Most of us would use a serial monitor e.g. `minicom` or miniterm:

```
python3 -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/serial0 9600
```

PS The port `/dev/ttyAMA0` may be connected to Bluetooth or serial,
It is better practice to use `/dev/serial0` which is guaranteed to be the serial port (if enabled),

Comment: By the way `cat /dev/serial0` is the same command as `cat </dev/serial0`

Comment: Ah, you're right @joan so when I did `cat /dev/ttyAMA0` that was fine and if I then did `echo "hello" > /dev/ttyAMA0` it works as intended.  Thanks.